# Send full ethernet packet to specific ip using C++

Tags: c++, sockets, packet-capture

I am trying to send a full packet to specific IP address. The point is that I already have full packet binary and I don't want it to be encapsulated into any additional packet headers. Here is my logic:

```
std::string destination_ip = "127.0.0.1";
uint16_t destination_port = 8080;
int socket_fd;

struct sockaddr_in socket_attrs;

if ((socket_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_PACKET, htons(ETH_P_ALL))) < 0)
{
    printf("Socket creation error\n");
    return false;
}

memset(&socket_attrs, '0', sizeof(socket_attrs));

socket_attrs.sin_family = AF_INET;
socket_attrs.sin_port = htons(destination_port);

if(inet_pton(AF_INET, destination_ip.c_str(), &socket_attrs.sin_addr)<=0)
{
    printf("Invalid IP address/ IP address not supported\n");
    return false;
}

if (connect(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&socket_attrs, sizeof(socket_attrs)) < 0)
{
    printf("Connection Failed\n");
    return false;
}

if((write(socket_fd , <PACKET_DATA> , <PACKET_SIZE>)) < 0){
    std::cout << "Error sending packets to the network" << std::endl;
    exit(1);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Connection Failed
```

Could anyone help me achieve my goal?

Comment: What do you mean by "[s]end full ethernet packet"? Do you mean that the packet data you have is the complete ethernet frame? Including IP and TCP headers?

Comment: Yes, I have a FULL packet binary including all headers

Comment: And remember that `connect` will set error codes that you can check to find out why it failed. Read the platform-specific manual page for `connect` to find out more.

Comment: Then you can't use TCP connections, unless you want to send the ethernet frame wrapped inside an TCP stream. You should probably do some more research about networking, including the different layers and socket types (like e.g. *raw* sockets) and much more.

Comment: You need `socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW)`. Anyway, try googling "send raw packet".

Comment: Actually after doing a lot of research, I tried multiple times. For example, when I use raw sockets, the packet gets encapsulated into additional headers (this smudges the packet)

Comment: By the way, this question is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): You look for help with a solution to an for us unknown problem. What is the *real* problem? *Why* do you need to send raw ethernet frames? Can you live with sending raw IP packets? What is the contents of the ethernet frame? There are simply to many unknowns for us to be able to really help you.

Comment: And also please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: I just need to send it as a test. No big picture here.. Also, the content of the packet doesn't matter here

Comment: @rustyx I tried your suggestion and it gives the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `libpcap`, [pcap_inject()](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap_inject.3pcap.html) in particular.

You cannot use `socket()`, using `IPPROTO_RAW` either, because L2(eth) and L3(ip) will be forged by the IP stack of the OS in this case too.

You need to inject the packet directly into the network card. If you want it delivered to an IP different from the original one, you have to "edit" the packet contents.

Example pasted from here: http://www.microhowto.info/howto/send_an_arbitrary_ethernet_frame_using_libpcap.html

```
char pcap_errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
pcap_errbuf[0]='\0';

pcap_t* pcap=pcap_open_live(if_name,65536,0,0,pcap_errbuf);
if (pcap_errbuf[0]!='\0') {
    fprintf(stderr,"%s",pcap_errbuf);
}

if (!pcap) {
    exit(1);
}

if (pcap_inject(pcap, <PACKET_DATA> , <PACKET_SIZE> )==-1) {
    pcap_perror(pcap,0);
    pcap_close(pcap);
    exit(1);
}

pcap_close(pcap)
```

If you don't want to edit the IP destination, the packet will be able to reach the other end of the wire only if you haven't switches/routers between the two peers.

As an alternative the OP suggesting to use a tunnel. It actually works (I tested it with `tcpreplay`) - you can use a GRE tunnel, which actually can transport ethernet traffic too.

On the two peers you can establish a *gretap* tunnel. I used these commands:

on host A (its IP address is 192.168.1.211):

```
ip link add gretap1 type gretap local 192.168.1.211 remote 192.168.1.64
ip link set gretap1 up
```

on host B (its IP address is 192.168.1.64):

```
ip link add gretap1 type gretap local 192.168.1.64 remote 192.168.1.211
ip link set gretap1 up
```

At this point it's possible to use the L2 GRE tunnel and let it transport ETH traffic using the gretap1 interfaces. On one peer I injected the traffic into the tunnel with the command:

```
tcpreplay -i gretap1 test.pcap
```

and on the other peer verified the traffic was transmitted capturing it on the gretap1 interface using wireshark or tcpdump.

Unfortunately there is a problem with this setup: the MTU of the tunnel is smaller than the MTU of the network, so it's not guaranteed that you can replay all the packets.

Comment: Could you please give me an example, because I am not able to find a good example of code snippets online

Comment: But where is the ip address to which the packet will be redirected ? All I see is that you only inject a packet on a local interface. We still need either to redirect the packet to a specific IP address or send it directly to some ip address without using the local interface. Did you get it?

Comment: the packet won't be redirected. It will be put "on-wire". the packet already has a destination IP address, in it's IP layer. Since you explicitly asked  not to tunnel it, the only option you have is to *edit* it, and to replace the IP with your intended destination.

Comment: Tunneling is a good option for me. Now, I am trying GRE tunnels, but it seems that GRE is only able to tunnel IP packets not ethernet packets. Do you know a way to tunnel a full ethernet packet?

Comment: Also I knew that unlike GIF tunnels, GRE tunnels cannot carry layer2 traffic. That's why I am thinking about GIF tunnels. Could you help me on my AskUbuntu question here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1109080/how-can-i-create-gif-tunnel-in-ubuntu

Comment: I've further edited the answer. I wasn't sure a tunnel was able to transport injected traffic, so I desired to test it before coming back.

Comment: Do you know how to do the same using ssh tunneling ? I need it because the tunnel will be established between AWS EC2 instances

Comment: use a VPN or PPP over SSH. AWS has their own networking product, to let different instances communicate each-other thought.

Comment: OK, I configured a tunnel using PPP over SSH. But when I write a packet on host A interface `ppp0` nothing reaches host B `ppp0` (unlike `gretap1`). I am unable to know why?

Comment: I solved my problem now. After creating `ppp0` on both machines, I created a gretap connecting the PPP interfaces together